# AngularJS, Mocha, Karma. testing controller, mocking service promise

Tags: angularjs, promise, mocha.js, karma-runner, chai

I'm using AngularJS, Karma, Mocha, Chai, Chai-as-promised, Sinon.

I'm trying the controller below. I am having trouble mocking the service User and test the .then() sections in the controller.

Controller Code

```
.controller('SignupPhoneCtrl', function(User, $scope) {
  $scope.sendPhoneNumber = function(countryCode, phoneNumber){
    User.sendPhoneNumber(countryCode, phoneNumber)
    .then(function(result){
      if(result == "success"){
        //I WANT TO TEST THIS SECTION
        return "success";
      }
        //I WANT TO TEST THIS SECTION
      return "fail";
    });
  }
})
```

ControllerTest Code

```
describe('Controller: Signup-phone', function() {
  var scope;
  var UserMock;
  var SignupPhoneCtrl;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('starter.controllers');
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $q){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    UserMock = {
      sendPhoneNumber: function(countryCode, phoneNumber){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        // console.log("called"); //This part is being called
        deferred.resolve('foo');
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    };
    SignupPhoneCtrl = $controller("SignupPhoneCtrl", {$scope: scope, User: UserMock});
  }))

  it('should return asdf', function(){
    scope.$digest();

    //WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE?

  })
});
```

I have tried the below but the assertion part is not being called.

```
scope.sendPhoneNumber(12, 53452123).then(function(result){
  result.should.equal("fail");  //THIS SECTION IS NOT CALLED
})
```

I have tried the below, but it gives error: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'promise.then.bind(promise)'

```
scope.sendPhoneNumber(12, 53452123).should.eventually.equal("fail");
```

`sendPhoneNumber(12, 53452123)` returns `Object{$$state: Object{status: 0}}`

I tried to add `sinon.spy(UserMock, 'sendPhoneNumber')`, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, `$scope.sendPhoneNumber` doesn't return anything. Try

```
return User.sendPhoneNumber(...
```

in your controller method.

---

Also, if you're just going to instantly resolve the promise in your mock, I've found this works nicely and saves you setting up a deferred object

```
UserMock = {
  sendPhoneNumber: function(countryCode, phoneNumber){
    return $q.when('foo');
  }
};
```

That being said, you probably want to be able to control the resolved value in each test so this makes more sense...

```
var scope;
var UserMock;
var SignupPhoneCtrl;
var deferred;

// snip

inject(function($rootScope, $controller, $q) {
    deferred = $q.defer();
    UserMock = {
        sendPhoneNumber: function() {
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    };
});

// snip

it('tests for success', inject(function($rootScope) {
    deferred.resolve('success');

    scope.sendPhoneNumber(...).then(...);

    $rootScope.$apply();
}));

it('tests for failure', inject(function($rootScope) {
    deferred.resolve('not success');

    scope.sendPhoneNumber(...).then(...);

    $rootScope.$apply();
}));
```

Comment: yes, I had tried to add `return User.sendPhoneNumber(...` but that alone did not solve it. I solved the problem using your code, I think it was thanks to the $rootScope or deferred. This way of using deferred is really nice Thank You.

Comment: Can anyone clarify the need to call the rootScope.apply(); ??

Comment: @gabriel it flushes any unresolved promises. Until you call it,  the promise will remain unresolved and the `then` callback will not have run